# Android Create Button Automatically When Data is Received

Tags: php, android, json

So I have an android project that gets data from php using JSON.
I want that if i received a data, two buttons will AUTOMATICALLY be created which is accept and decline and if i receive another data another set of two buttons will be created. I am thinking to create buttons inside the loop but I don't know if it's possible in android? Is this possible?
Thanks

Comment: It is possible, what you have tried so far?

Comment: What's an issue of creating. Just create the two buttons programatically as

Button yesBtn = new Button(this);
yesBtn.setText(Yes);
yourLayout.addView(yesBtn);

Button noBtn = new Button(this);
noBtn.setText(no);
yourLayout.addView(noBtn);

Comment: hello can you give me a hint please. does it use onclick listeners or something? i'm really confused on what to search. can you give me a lesson/guide link. i would really appreciate it.

Comment: Google: "android create button programmatically"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the appropriate import to your Activity:

```
import android.widget.Button;
```

Then create a new button object within the onCreate method:

```
Button myButton = new Button(this);
myButton.setText("Press Me");
```

Finally add the button to the layout:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout1);   
layout.addView(myButton);
```

To add buttons dynamically in a loop and add listener to it, you can do like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<nob;i++) {
Button btn = new Button(this);
btn.setId(i+1);
btn.setText("Button"+(i+1));
btn.setLayoutParams(lprams);
final int index = i;
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    void onClick(View v) {
        Log.i("TAG", "The index is" + index);
    }
});
 dynamicview.addView(btn);
}
```

Comment: can i put that in a loop where everytime i receive a data it would create a button and has onclick listeners on it. so it would always create a button every time a new data is received in a loop?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. The context could be `this` or `getActivity()` depending on where you are calling from.

`Button button = new Button(context);`